# Remove trailing json comma with command line tools

Tags: json, bash, sed

I want to remove trailing comma from json as,

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "object": {
    "key2": "value2", // <- remove comma
  },
  "key3": "value3", // <- remove comma
}
```

I came up with,

```
tr -d '\n' | \
sed -E 's:,(\s*}):\1:g' | \
jq .
```

and it works but I want to get this fully in `sed`.

I came up with,

```
sed -E '/,\s*$/ { N; s:,\s*(\n\s*},?):\1: }'
```

which works for above input but fails for

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "object": {
    "key2": "value2",
  },
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4", // <- remove comma
}
```

as `N` reads the next line and starts over from the line after next.

```
// output sed -E '/,\s*$/ { N;l }' using l/look command
{
  "key1": "value1",\n  "object": {$
  "key1": "value1",
  "object": {
    "key2": "value2",\n  },$
    "key2": "value2",
  },
  "key3": "value3",\n  "key4": "value4",$
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4",
}
```

**Update:**

Adding another example for testing:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "object1": {
    "object2": {
      "key2": "value2"
    },
  },
  "key3": "value3",
}
```

**Update:**

This is working for whatever I've thrown at it.

```
sed -E -n 'H; x; s:,(\s*\n\s*}):\1:; P; ${x; p}' | \
    sed '1 d'
```

Explanation:

```
sed -E -n 'H; x; P; ${x; p}'
```

`-n 'H; x'` to get every line appended to the next line in pattern space (except for the last line which is simply printed with `${x; p}`)

and

```
s:,(\s*\n\s*}):\1:;
```

to remove the trailing comma in the pattern space.

Comment: Can you just fix the thing that is generating the invalid JSON instead? Because this isn't really the sort of problem you're going to solve robustly using `sed`.

Comment: There are JSON libraries for practically all languages. If you're getting invalid JSON like this, it's a sure sign that the creator rolled their own code instead of using a proper library, and they didn't know what they were doing. Tell them to fix it.

Comment: Because if they can't even get commas right, they've probably got other problems as well, such as escaping special characters in strings. You'll drive yourself crazy trying to work around all their bugs.

Comment: Anything you do will probably fail for something like `key: "foo,}"`, it will remove the comma that's inside the string.

Comment: *"I want to remove trailing comma from json"* -- your input is not JSON (as [JSON](https://json.org)s do not have trailing commas). Assuming your input **is** JSON, `sed` is not the tool for handling it. Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or a programming language.

Comment: I understand that it's not valid json, but it's convenient for adhoc testing. I'm editing the json input for quick testing for apis. I already have a sed command to remove `//` and wanted something to remove the trailing comma.

Comment: @axiac `jq` does not allow comments and trailing commas, hence this post. I'm piping the stripped output to it.

Comment: A little update to your regex did it for me -- thanks! -- now it works with closing } and ] as well: sed -E -n 'H; x; s:,(\s*\n\s*[]}]):\1:; P; ${x; p}' | sed '1 d'

Comment: I've `'H; x; s:,(\s*\n\s*(}|])):\1:; P'`, and it's working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the input seems to be some kind of extension of JSON, you could use a command-line tool intended for such extensions.  For example:

```
$ hjson -j < input.txt
```

or:

```
$ any-json --input-format=hjson input.txt
```

### Output in both cases

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "object": {
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

Comment: Good answer! On the other hand, json should just support the trailing comma! :)

Comment: Thank you so much!  The second method works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Using the hold buffer:

```
sed '/^ *\}/{H;x;s/\([^}]\),\n/\1\n/;b};x;/^ *}/d' input
```

This is just a sed exercise, I don't think sed is the right tool for this job. It also needs a newline at the end or that the file ends with a `}`.

Comment: I added another sample json for testing where this `sed` fails.

Comment: This is not working for the new sample json I added. Are you sure this work? I'm on and `sed (GNU sed) 4.5` with `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)`, so I'm interested in the difference. Btw, I updated with an answer.

Comment: Can you comment on this: https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/Xz9OQSumVr/aw7rCulg/RiM6rjY2RlMnJk8/xhBIWCfVAiVAimr1U/7/r@ZSUFDKTq00VLJSUCpLzClNNVTSAYnlJ2WlJpeAhEFK4AJGcAGIPiO4PiMlsHAtSDeYAEkbw6WNgcbWAgA

Comment: Overall the accepted answer is better answer for the question that is titled now as hjson handles comments (both line, block), trailing comma, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction with `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer with `sed` but a (`python`) solution:

```
# load as python dictionary
d = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "object": {
    "key2": "value2",
  },
  "key3": "value3",
}

import json

json.dumps(d) # valid json string
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#processing-not-quite-valid-json seems to be your answer

```
# this works
echo '{"a": 1,}' | jq -n -f /dev/stdin

# as well as this
cat <<EOF | jq -n -f /dev/stdin
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "object": {
    "key2": "value2",
  },
  "key3": "value3",
}
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it by loading the json as yaml with python pyyaml library and worked fine.

So for this example:

```
$ echo '{"a": 1,}' | jq
parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 1, column 9
```

pyyaml fixes the input:

```
$ echo '{"a": 1,}' | python3 -c "import sys, json, yaml; print(json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin)))" | jq

{
  "a": 1
}
```

A more complex example:

```
$ echo '{"a": [1,],}' | python3 -c "import sys, json, yaml; print(json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin)))" | jq

{
  "a": [
    1
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in GNU awk. It uses `"` as field separator and removes commas before `[ \n]*}` from odd fields (outside quotes, will probably fail for `"escaped \" inside"`). Added `"key4": "value4,}",` to the file:

```
$ cat file
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "object": {
    "key2": "value2",
  },
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4,}",
}
```

The script processes the whole file as a single record (`RS="^$"`) so it might not work for big files as-is:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\""
    RS="^$"
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {                         # or i+=2 and remove the if
        if(i%2)
            $i=gensub(/,([ \n]*\})/,"\\1","g",$i)
    }
}1' file
```

Output:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "object": {
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4,}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sed and awk commands wasn’t working for me, so I ended up writing a small `remove-json-trailing-comma.js` file

```js
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require("fs");

const regex = /,(?!\s*?[{["'\w])/g;

const files = process.argv.splice(2);
for (let file of files) {
    const input = readFileSync(file).toString();
    let correct = input.replace(regex, '');
    writeFileSync(file, correct);
}
```

And then I could use it like this `node remove-json-trailing-comma.js file.json` (and work also with multiples files like `node remove-json-trailing-comma.js **/package.json`)