# Process multi-line json with trailing commas

Tags: python, json, pyspark, jq

I have JSON in files with text contents like:

```
{
    "id": "01",
    "Variables": [
        {
            "Name": "myvar",
            "Value": "15"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "01",
    "Variables": [
        {
            "Name": "myvar",
            "Value": "15"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note this example has 2 records, each split over multiple lines with a comma between each.

This comma-delimiter between records makes it difficult to process e.g. with jq:

```
$ cat myfile.json | jq -s
```

parse error: Expected value before ',' at line 9...

Or with python:

```
import json
with open("alert_feedback_20220424.json", "r") as f:
    j = json.load(f)
```

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 9...

Ultimately I actually want to read this data with spark:

```
spark.read.option(
    'sep', ','
).option(
    'header', False
).option(
    'multiLine', True
).csv(
    'file://my/project/data/myfile.json'
)
```

But this doesn't seem to have parsed the json correctly. I'll add details when I have time on request.

Links to solutions tried:

- [parse error: Expected value before ',' at line 71, column 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64457685/parse-error-expected-value-before-at-line-71-column-2)
- [Python: Change multi-line json String to single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63398199/python-change-multi-line-json-string-to-single-line)
- [Remove trailing json comma with command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53201028/remove-trailing-json-comma-with-command-line-tools)

How can I programmatically remove this comma after each JSON record, or otherwise format this json to be parsed correctly?

Comment: Couldn't you wrap all records with `[]`? During saving the file, on save file with some `sed` tool or during reading the content before parsing to json?

Comment: Adding the square brackets at runtime could work programmatically, but I'm not sure this is possible when read from S3 in a spark application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jq`, read in the whole file as raw text using the `-R` option, receive it as one long string using the `-s` option, wrap that string in brackets and use `fromjson` to decode it from JSON. You should now have a valid array.

```sh
jq -Rs '"[\(.)]" | fromjson' myfile.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": "01",
    "Variables": [
      {
        "Name": "myvar",
        "Value": "15"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "01",
    "Variables": [
      {
        "Name": "myvar",
        "Value": "15"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5UZll8AOja)

Use `.[]` to have individual items (without commas in between):

```sh
jq -Rs '"[\(.)]" | fromjson[]' myfile.json
```

```json
{
  "id": "01",
  "Variables": [
    {
      "Name": "myvar",
      "Value": "15"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "id": "01",
  "Variables": [
    {
      "Name": "myvar",
      "Value": "15"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ZEgaItRpzu)

Comment: Thanks! This is more workable than manual solution. Not sure if there's a way to wrap data read from spark this way before parsing the result. Other than downloading, running jq, and uploading back before reading.